# Facedetector not recognize faces

Tags: android, face-detection

I have the following code but Facedetector dont recognize faces, any ideas?

```
android.media.FaceDetector.Face[] Faces = new FaceDetector.Face[4];
Bitmap bitmap;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getAbsolutePath());
if(bitmap!=null){
FaceDetector f = new FaceDetector(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 4);
f.findFaces(bitmap, Faces);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to do the job, do you get an error or it just doesn't recognize faces? How many different images did you tried?

Comment: I tried and this returns some values, not correct but it works something :)

Comment: That's the real problem, when i use a photo of a person FaceDetector don't recognize anything but if i try with a photo of a wall or something like this, it works :(. I dont know what im doing wrong...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you tried displaying the search results on actual image, maybe this would help you get some more info, when you see what actually happens.

Comment: Also I have noticed this `The bitmap must be in 565 format (for now).`, maybe there is a problem?

Comment: If you are still there, I tried some editing and displaying Rects over the image, bitmap has to be in 565 format, and it recognizes faces with certain errors, it detects faces but it detects some other stuff as faces or it doesn't recognize some faces. But it works somehow :)

Comment: Thank you a lot Marko, i was using 565 format with the same results. I think that i must use another face detection method ... post me an answer and i will rate you! You are helping me a lot.

Comment: Don't care about ratings, like to help when it is a good question worth the time, not some lazy wanna be programmer who is too cool to use google first. Cheers and enjoy your work.